# Make app show view only when opening from notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am making an app, and their is going to be a local notification that asks you a question. I want it so that if the app is opened from the notification or maybe within 5 minutes, a certain view is showed that is not there when launching the app normally. Im using a UITabBar application if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect whether the app just launched from a notification by checking the `launchOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary * userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (userInfo) {
        // Ok, launched from a notification. Do stuff here
    }

    // ...

    return YES;
}
```

where `userInfo` will cointain the notification payload sent by the server.